# Trouble with the Path outset in Inkscape

Tags: kubuntu, inkscape

I am using the latest version of Kubuntu, and I am having some trouble in Inkscape. Not sure if it's a glitch, or I am doing something wrong. When I try to outset a path, it makes a horrible random shape instead of doing an outset. Here's a gif:

[image: Since I cannot embed it because of my reputation, you must click this link.]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Arre all those shapes you selected: 1) a single path, 2) a group with several paths inside, or 3) independent paths? Did you try dynamic offset, to see where it goes nuts?